# CSS Making an Active State Nav element with existing code

Tags: css, menu

Guys I am working with another person's code and was wondering how I would get the nav in question to display an 'active state'. In other words, how do I have that nav item on that page be active and show a different bg color / text color? here is the CSS and HTML, it's simple, I know... but I can't figure out how to get this active state to work.

**CSS:**

```
.menu {width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
.menu a.menuitem {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    display: block;
    position: relative; /*To help in the anchoring of the ".statusicon" icon image*/
    width: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a.menuitem:visited, .menu .menuitem:active {color:#9ca1a6; text-decoration: none;}




.menu a.menuitem .statusicon { /*CSS for icon image that gets dynamically added to headers*/position:absolute; top:5px; right:5px; border: none;}
.menu a.menuitem:hover {
    background: #6dd0f7;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.menu div.submenu { /*DIV that contains each sub menu*/ width:auto; margin:0; padding:0;}

.menu div.submenu ul { /*UL of each sub menu*/ list-style-type:none; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;}

.menu div.submenu ul li{border-bottom:1px solid #AFAFAF; line-height:12px; margin:0; padding:0;}

.menu div.submenu ul li a{display:block; font-size:12px; color:#383838; text-decoration: none; margin:0; padding:5px 10px 5px 20px;}

.menu div.submenu ul li a:link {color:#383838; text-decoration:none;}

.menu div.submenu ul li a:visited {color:#383838; text-decoration:none;}

.menu div.submenu ul li a:active {background:#D7EEFF; color:#0164B5; text-decoration:none;}

.menu div.submenu ul li a:hover {background:#D7EEFF; color:#0164B5; text-decoration:none;}


HTML:

         <div class="menu">
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="seller-account-store-profile.html">My Store Profile</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Messages (241)</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Account Settings</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Fees & Activities</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Notifications</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Contact Support</a>
          </div>
```

Comment: `:active` is only the mid-click state. If you want to set the current page's nav item, you'll have to set up some way to do it (usually by adding your own .active class or something), or if you're using a CMS, there's probably some integrated active class.

Answer (score 2):

The `:active` css selector selects the link only when you click it (mousedown). See **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)**.

To display the navigation item of the current page in another way, you need to add an extra class to that link, and add your style definitions to that class. For example:

`<a class="menuitem submenuheader active" href="">Messages (241)</a>`

and style it with:

`.menu a.active {
    /* your definitions */
}`

Comment: Nice, ok it worked  BUT i cant seem to override the existing 'visited' link color from here....menu a.menuitem:visited, .menu .menuitem:active {color:#9ca1a6; text-decoration: none;}  how do i make JUST the active state a white text and not affect the visited portion?

Comment: .menu a.active { color: white !important; }

Answer (score 0):

Create a "current" class and set it to the element that is currently being shown.

**Example CSS**

```
div.menu a.current {
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #6dd0f7;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="seller-account-store-profile.html">My Store Profile</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader current" href="">Messages (241)</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="" class="current">Account Settings</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Fees & Activities</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Notifications</a>
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="">Contact Support</a>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcmaD/

Comment: hmn ya that didn't work. Need to apply it to , say , this one...<a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="seller-account-store-profile.html">My Store Profile</a>

Comment: Need this style for the 'you're on this page and this wont change till you leave' look... background: #6dd0f7;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;

Comment: Then that would be `<a class="menuitem submenuheader current" href="seller-account-store-profile.html">My Store Profile</a>` with the CSS specified above.

Comment: maybe this double class is messin it up?   <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="" class="current">Account Settings</a>

Comment: Yeah, you cannot have two class attributes. Merge it into `class="menuitem submenuheader current"`

Comment: Hmn it was working fine before with the addition of the active code you first sent...but to get the font face to remain white and not grab the visited style of grey  its not working..now its back to the default state

Comment: Glad it worked. :) Mark the question as answered if you're happy with it.